# Saving state of a Switch component in a stack navigator

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

I am new to programming. I'm setting up some boolean switches to allow the user to select preferences. The code I have got so far seems to work as had many issues with state being stuck or not toggling at all. Now my issue is that when I back out of the screen I'm working on and go back in, it always goes back to "true" state, so switches are always on when I go onto the page.

Is there something wrong with my code that the state doesn't persist, or should I move the state to redux store? If so how would I do this?

Multiple web articles and some youtube tutorials, they all seem to work on a barebones single page "Hello World" app. Can't find any real world examples to work with.

```
class SettingsMarketingPreferences extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            switchone: true,
            switchtwo: true,
            switchthree: true
        };
    }

    <Switch
        onValueChange={value => this.setState({ switchone: value })}
        value={this.state.switchone}/>
```

Ideally it would save the state of the switches, there are three I just decided to share how one was built to avoid repetition. Long term goal is to attach it to a ID token so we would be able to see who has opted in or out for our marketing information.

Comment: Where is your render method? Also, you can use AsyncStorage to make it

Comment: I cut out render to only include info I thought was absolutely crucial! sorry. I had looked at Async and it said it was depreciated and guided me to this other page, do you recommend (https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage) ? sorry for questions I am genuinely curious.

Comment: Ah, I get it. Is not crucial, but sometimes errors comes from this constructor or some things like that (that seems obvious). 
Yes, use that one!

Answer (score 0):

```
<ToggleSwitch
    isOn={this.state.toggle1}
    onColor="green"
    offColor="gray"
    size='medium'
    onToggle={()=>this.togglechange1()}
/>
```

Comment: import ToggleSwitch from 'toggle-switch-react-native'
then,put a  state={toggle1:false},
put a simple condition 
   togglechange1(){
    this.setState({toggle1:!this.state.toggle1})
  }

Comment: togglechange1(){
    this.setState({toggle1:!this.state.toggle1})
  }

Comment: I cant use react-native's own switch?